# set display: block in javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a problem with my code. I want to set display: block when i click on "start" button. I created addevenlistener on click but something is wrong. Can anyone to help me?

```js
const ulElement = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");


function changeSize() {
  ulElement.style.display = "block";
}

btn.addEventListener("click", changeSize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>list</title>
    <style>
      li {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
   

    <button>Start</button>
    <ul>
      <li>element 1</li>
      <li>element 2</li>
      <li>element 3</li>
      <li>element 4</li>
      <li>element 5</li>
      <li>element 6</li>
      <li>element 7</li>
      <li>element 8</li>
      <li>element 9</li>
      <li>element 10</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is an error message in your console. What have you done to fix that? `document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, which does not have a style attribute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind but if you change:

```
li {
        display: none;
      }
```

to:

```
ul {
        display: none;
      }
```

And if you change:

```
const ulElement = document.querySelectorAll("li");
```

to:

```
const ulElement = document.querySelector("ul");
```

Then it will work the list will appear after clicking on the button....

Answer (score 1):

You have `querySelectorAll` you have selected all the liElements and you should have an array node lists not a single element hence why you can't just use `e.style.display` on an array, what you need to do is loop through all the items and set thier display one by one

```js
const ulElement = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");


function changeSize() {
  ulElement.forEach(e => e.style.display = "block")
  //ulElement.style.display = "block";
}

btn.addEventListener("click", changeSize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>list</title>
    <style>
      li {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
   

    <button>Start</button>
    <ul>
      <li>element 1</li>
      <li>element 2</li>
      <li>element 3</li>
      <li>element 4</li>
      <li>element 5</li>
      <li>element 6</li>
      <li>element 7</li>
      <li>element 8</li>
      <li>element 9</li>
      <li>element 10</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```